# Remove watch on YouTube logo on video

Tags: html, youtube

I have looked around the internet for a method to remove the YouTube logo from their iFrame player.

I am using

```
<iframe width="550" height="314" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vidid?modestbranding=1&amp;rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

which removes the 'watch on YouTube' button from the bottom actions panel however it adds the YouTube logo watermark to the bottom right of the video and when I hover over it says watch on YouTube.

I have tried changing 'embed' to 'v' which removes it but then it doesnt work on iPad/phone.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't use YouTube (and their bandwidth, transcode farm, social network, captioning systems, etc, etc, etc) if you don't want them to have any credit.

Comment: There are in fact 2 links which play the same video and the second link has ALL YouTube branding in tack so I am happy to give them credit. There are a lot of tut's showing how to remove their logo but for some reason on my versions, it only moves it to another location. Using the 'v' method removes it completely but I cant use that method.

Comment: Vimeo might be a good suggestion for your needs

Comment: We had Vimeo going but then the method the client was using started only supporting Flash (apparently) so they asked me to update to their YouTube version. Maybe I will look back into Vimeo because it seems strange they would only allow Flash!

Comment: Also tell them that flash is fighting an increasing battle with html5 so they may want to avoid that. The biggest reason not to use flash tho is because it s detrimental to SEO efforts.

Comment: I agree however sometimes is a battle trying to convince people of that

Comment: Vimeo supports HTML5 -> https://developer.vimeo.com/player/embedding

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, the most you can do is to add the `modestbranding=1` option to the URL, but this only gets rid of the title and youtube link on the top of the player.

I don't think you can get rid of the bottom right one that appears when you hover.

Source: https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#modestbranding

Answer (score 1):

You can upload it from google drive!

Answer (score 0):

If you use modestbranding=1 you can't use showinfo=0. You can only use 1 or the other. Also, if you use modestbranding=1 it must come first right after the url.

Example:

```
 https://youtube.com/embed/vidid?modestbranding=1
```